# High CPU usage when reproducing media

Tags: 16.04, graphics, intel-graphics, performance

After upgrading my system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.04.2 (fresh install) I detected high CPU usage when reproducing videos in a web browser (Firefox and Chrome) or with a video reproducer, which causes my laptop to freeze. With the command top I can see that the process involved has a CPU usage of >100%. First I thought that the responsible of the slow performance was kidle_inject so I disabled it, but the problem still remained. Then I udpated the graphic card drivers with the Intel Graphics Linux tool and didn't work. My laptop specs:

- Intel Core i5
- 6 GB RAM
- Intel HD 4000

What else can I try? Is this a common problem?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit your question adding: CPU model i5-???, i.e. output from `grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo`; LapTop model and manufacturer name; While under load, output from `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`;